# Fortran references to variables

Tags: fortran

I am extremely new to Fortran, so forgive any ignorance in this question.
Anyway I am working on optimizing some simulation software.

To be more clear the subroutine I am editing initializes some static variables at the start and they should be the same no matter what the starting conditions are.

The problem is I have another piece of coding calling this subroutine across each of its time steps reinitializing hundreds of variables, that should have just stayed the same. To fix this I have created a derived type that includes all these variables from other modules in the program, and I am editing the software to initialize the derived type variables instead of the module variables so that I can just refer across different time steps.

My question is, am i doing uneeded work. If I instead just took all the initialization stuff and put it in a subroutine outside of my main program, and then linked these at compilation, would all the variables retain their values across function calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable that should be initialized once and never changed, give it the parameter attribute:

`real, parameter :: pi = 3.141592`

The compiler will treat the "variable" as a constant that can't be changed.  If you mistakenly try to change such a variable, the compiler will inform you of your mistake.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Kind of but the problem is that would require about as much work as what im doing now. 

What i was wondering is how modules work. If I intialize a variable from a module in one subroutine will it keeps its value if I include that module in another subroutine

Answer (score -2):

I can't tell what you are doing, but FORTRAN is a 3GL and it passes parameters by reference. If you want variables from the main to be in subroutines, you need to put it in a common block. COMMON blocks are like global variables in C.

Comment: Under no circumstances should anyone be writing new Fortran with common blocks.  Beyond that, the suggestion that the only way to pass variables to a subroutine is to use a common block is wrong.  Just wrong.